# I can't verify from a button click if an edit text has no value in it

Tags: android-studio

I have a button and an EditText with input type numbers only in my main xml. I want to check all values entered. What i did until now and works fine is that i can check if starts with zero and then toast an attention msg, if value is zero also a toast msg and if the value entered is bigger then 25. This work perfectly into my onClick procedure from the button in xml.

What i cant solve is when you delete all the numbers in the edit text and will be empty. I tryed a lot of codes and all the time my app crashes.

My code from xml for the Edit Text:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/numarJocuri"
                android:background="@drawable/decor_fundal_la_edittext"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="2"
                android:textColor="#be9e51"
                android:textColorHint="#c8e6c9"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="1"/>
```

My code from xml for the button:

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buton_incepeti"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ok1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:onClick="beginClick"
                android:paddingLeft="30dip"
                android:paddingRight="26dip"
                android:text="@string/incepeti"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

What i did on my java main code at the button click procedure:

```
//BEGIN CLICK
public void beginClick(View view) {

    //initialize the edit text
    final EditText edMeu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numarJocuri);

    String s1;

    s1 = edMeu.getText().toString().trim();

    int numar1;

    numar1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);

    //the value entered to not be bigger then 25
    if (numar1 > 25) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.atentie_numar_maxim), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    //to not start with zero
    if (edMeu.getText().toString().startsWith("0")) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.nu_incepe_cu_zero), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }


}//SFARSIT BEGIN CLICK
```

So, until now all of this works.

I tryed this but not worked for me here on button click. In other activity at an alertdialog this code works fine.

```
//check to not be empty
            String verif_text1 = edMeu.getText().toString().trim();

            if(verif_text1.isEmpty() || verif_text1.length() == 0 || verif_text1.equals("") || verif_text1 == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.msg_null_values), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            } //end checking
```

Also i tryed to check the lenght of that edit text, not worked.

Answer (score 1):

you may try isEmpty() to check the text is empty or not

```
edMeu.getText().toString().isEmpty()
```

Comment: i tryed this , but not work.


//to not be empty
        if (edMeu.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "my message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

When i select and delete all the value in the edit text and i click the button, app crashes...said "Unfortunately App Closed"

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved it. This is how:

The main problem was that me tryed to check that edit text after i was transforming his value into integer, so after i readed more carefully the errors displayed on android console i figured where the problem was.

Code into my java button

```
//begin click for the button
public void beginClick(View view) {

    //initialize 
    final EditText edMeu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numarJocuri);

    String s1;

    s1 = edMeu.getText().toString().trim();

    //here is the verification for not to be empty or no value entered
    if (s1.toString().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.games_not_entered), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

//transform into integer values
//after the string was checked above

    int numar1;

    numar1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);

    //to not be bigger then 25, after is transformed in integer
    if (numar1 > 25) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.atentie_numar_maxim), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    //to not start with zero values
    if (edMeu.getText().toString().startsWith("0")) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.nu_incepe_cu_zero), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
} //end of begin click for the button
```

That is all, was not hard, but requires more attention when writing codes.